# why is my website is pushed to the left when resizing in responsive mode?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have made this website as a practice portfolio website for myself and my website is pushed to the left whenever its smaller than particular size. it used to be around 600px but I removed the whole code and rewrote the website again but I checked it at early phases and still suffers from this problem which I cant find the reason for it. so I stopped coding and came straight here for help.
please help me this is the third time I'm trying to build this website and still have this problem.
something else i noticed is that althoug i have scroll x hidden i still have this tiny scroll to left when resizing the website.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBZjc.gif)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
  color: rgb(218, 214, 214);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
/*NAVBAR----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.navbar {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.116);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.icon-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.icon-list li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.icon-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(180, 148, 158);
}
.icon-list a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.images {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
/*INFO---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.info {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 200px;

  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.info p {
  margin: 0 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.info h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(177, 164, 164);
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.info h2 {
  color: rgb(192, 184, 153);
  font-weight: 400;
}
.info h3 {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.shadow {
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: rgba(34, 33, 33, 0.336);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Ashkan Naeimipoor</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
<body>
       <nav class="navbar">
              <ul class="icon-list">
                     <li><a href=""><img class="images" src="./images/navbar/home.png" alt=""><br>HOME</a></li>
                     <li><a href=""><img class="images" src="./images/navbar/resume.png" alt=""><br>GET RESUME</a></li>
                     <li><a href=""><img class="images" src="./images/navbar/about.png" alt=""><br>ABOUT</a></li>
                     <li><a href=""><img  class="images"  src="./images/navbar/contact-book.png" alt=""><br>CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
       </nav>
<div class="container">
      
       <div class="info">
             <div class="shadow">
              <h1>Ashkan Naeimipoor</h1>
              <h2>Front-End Developer</h2>
              <h3>Objective</h3>
              <p>As a Front-End Developer, to be responsible for 
                     producing high quality solutions for company customers; bringing growing understanding of Modern HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, and passionate ability to learn and develope 
                     while working in the team of experts under a 
                     skillful and talented management.</p>
             </div>
              </div>
             

             
       
</div>



      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by moved to left. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .info class, you are using 100px on padding. That's too large in smaller screen. You can reduce it using [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

I'll also suggest changing .info class into:

```
.info {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1060px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: the issue was any margin or padding I have had on blocks in my code and the margins and paddings  pushed items out of their container thank you for finding that issue and helping me fixed it. hope you have great day.